# How to change Apache root directory

Tags: apache, apache2

I know that there are several other questions asking this. However, I still have problems.

I am trying to change my Apache root server directory from the default `/var/www/html` on my Debian server. To do this, I modified `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to have `DocumentRoot /var/www` instead of `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`. After doing this and saving it, I ran `apache2ctl restart` to reload the server. However, the server still looks for files in `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www`. Is there something else I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are "landing" in the VirtualHost you are modifying.

You can check the virtualhosts being loaded with this command:

```
apachectl -S
```

Note: It is not ServerRoot what you are describing, it is DocumentRoot, there is a big diffrence between each, so better name them properly.